# Editing a text file in Delphi

Tags: delphi, text

I got a edit and a listbox on my canvas, the listbox content is loaded with the content of an txt file, In order to do that I used the code:

```
  listbox1.Items.LoadFromFile('data\data.dat');
```

When typing the name on edit I want to highlight it on the listbox, so I used the code:

```
procedure TformMain.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
const
   indexStart = -1;
 var
   search : array[0..128] of Char;
begin
   StrPCopy(search, Edit1.Text) ;
   ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Perform(LB_SELECTSTRING, indexStart, LongInt(@search));
end;
```

Now with a button on my canvas I want to delete the selected name from the txt.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a sidenote about [`Perform`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform) and even common parameter casting. Always try to cast values into the natural parameter types used by the function itself. In this case you should use `LPARAM` casting instead of `LongInt`, so your code would be like `ListBox1.Perform(LB_SELECTSTRING, IndexStart, LPARAM(@Search));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to delete the text that matches the edit control:

```
var
  newS : string;
...
newS := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
Delete(newS,Pos(Edit1.Text,newS),Length(Edit1.Text));
ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex] := newS;
```

If you want to remove the whole line:

```
ListBox1.Items.Delete(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
```